# Can we sort List<T> from Spring boot Pageable or sort page from PageImpl?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting, java-8, pagination

**I have business logic to convert List to Page in Spring Boot.**

In that code, my pageable sort doesn't sort in the output.

**Is there a way if I can sort via pageable or sort List from pageable.getSort()?**

- Note: I'm using new PageImpl() to convert List to Page.*

  int start = (int) pageable.getOffset();
  int end = (start + pageable.getPageSize()) > List.size() ? List.size() : (start + pageable.getPageSize());
  Page paginatedList = new PageImpl(floorsheetList.subList(start, end), pageable, list.size());

**I actually get sorted= true but data won't sort.**

```
sort: {
sorted: true,
unsorted: false,
empty: false
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
Turns out PageImpl cannot sort the data. So have to manually sort it via Collections or any other APIs.
```

Comment: Spring Data has support for `Page` directly, so if you're retrieving your list of objects from a database using Spring data, you could just refactor that code to return a `Page` directly, which will be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out PageImpl cannot sort the data. So have to manually sort it via Collections or any other APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You using pageImpl like you set variable into new page, so contents in page isn't sort.

You get sorted = true because in pageable you set sort.

If you want contents in page sorted, you should using Collections.sort to sort List contents before set PageImpl.

Comment: Thanks. I had missed in documentation regarding PageImpl cannot do sorting part. It was my mistake. :)